# Discrepancy between calculated and experimental enthalpy change of formation? Hydrogen Iodide

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

Afterthought: See edits below!

---

$$\ce{1/2 H2(g) + 1/2 I2(g) -> HI(g)} \qquad \Delta_\mathrm f H^\circ=26.5\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$$

source: https://atct.anl.gov/Thermochemical%20Data/version%201.122/species/?species_number=47

However, from bond enthalpies (exact! though I do not know at what temperature)

$E(H-H) = 436 \ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$
$E(I-I) = 151 \ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$
$E(H-I) = 299 \ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$

Therefore, $\Delta \mathrm H = \{436 + 151 - 2(299)\}/2 = -5.5 \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$

This page also gives a negative enthalpy of reaction....
https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_Kentucky/UK%3A_General_Chemistry/13%3A_Fundamental_Equilibrium_Concepts/13.3%3A_Shifting_Equilibria_-_Le_Chateliers_Principle

Numerical agreement is not expected, however, the difference in signs would lead one to wrongly conclude whether the reaction is endothermic or exothermic, a problem when trying to apply Le Chatelier's principle....

What's wrong?

Is this significant: [Does the bond dissociation enthalpy vary with temperature?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7442/does-the-bond-dissociation-enthalpy-vary-with-temperature?rq=1)

---

EDIT:

Sorry! Wrong equation! Let me clean up my mistake!

$$\ce{1/2 H2(g) + 1/2 I2(s) -> HI(g)} \qquad \Delta_\mathrm f H^\circ=26.5\ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$$

Enthalpy change of formation: iodine starts off as a solid!

$$\ce{I2(s) -> I2(g)} \qquad \Delta H_{sub} = 13056 \ \mathrm{cal\ mol^{-1}} \approx 54.63 \ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$$

Determination of the heat of sublimation of iodine: A physical chemistry laboratory experiment
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed064p551

for $\ce{1/2 H2(g) + 1/2 I2(g) -> HI(g)}$, $\Delta H = \Delta H_f - \Delta H_{sub} = 26.5 - 54.63/2 \approx -0.815 \ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$

In fact, the reaction is exothermic!

$$\ce{H_2 (g) + I_2 (g) -> 2HI(g)} \qquad \Delta H_r (0K)  \approx - 9.5 \ \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}$$
[https://atct.anl.gov/Thermochemical%20Data/version%201.122/reaction/?&species_number[]=1&species_number[]=47&species_number[]=60&c1=1&c2=-2&c3=1](https://atct.anl.gov/Thermochemical%20Data/version%201.122/reaction/?&species_number%5B%5D=1&species_number%5B%5D=47&species_number%5B%5D=60&c1=1&c2=-2&c3=1)

---

By the way, this question was inspired by the following CIE A-levels problem: Chemistry 9701 October/November 2021 Paper 2 Variant 2 Question 2 (9701 Oct Nov P22 Q2)

Comment: There are playing roles component heat capacities, and their different quantization due different masses.

Comment: By other words, H2, HI and I2 have at the same temperature the same mean translational energy, but due rotation and vibration quantization the different mean rotational and vibrational energy. I do not say it counts for all the difference, but it is a contributing factor.

Comment: Based on a [1983 PhD thesis](https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/dissertations/AAI8318683/), the first value (positive) seems more likely.

Comment: A [1977 paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0021961477901690) has similar values for HI in the vapor phase, and also gives the (negative) value for HI in the aqueous phase. The internet has a wide range of values, i.e. probably did not catch up but is copying from older textbooks and problems sets.